# Firestore local junit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine, junit, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a library to get a mocked version of Firestore for local unit tests like the one for google app engines datastore:

`private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
      new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());` (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting#datastore-memcache)

The Firestore mock of this file https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-firestore/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/firestore/FirestoreTest.java does not work:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.sendRequest(FirestoreImpl.java:399)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.UpdateBuilder.commit(UpdateBuilder.java:467)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.WriteBatch.commit(WriteBatch.java:41)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentReference.set(DocumentReference.java:156)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreMocked.test(FirestoreMocked.kt:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
```